# Twenty Fourteen responsive CSS

Tags: css, responsive

I today install on wordpress new responsive theme ''Twenty Fourteen'',
I try to edit css, try to change bg color of header menu,
I can't found in css where i change bg color,
I before do this a million times on old not responsive css, how i edit responsive css ?

Thanks.

Comment: This forum does not provide theme customization support so your question is off topic as it does not relate specifically to WordPress Development.

Comment: @BradDalton Any question regarding the inner workings of a bundled theme is **on-topic**. You can check out [this discussion](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/3862/31545) on meta stack :-)

Comment: Personally i'm happy to and have answered many theme customization questions relating to any default theme but its not core WordPress and i don't think CSS Media Queries for themes should be covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background colour of the header in Twenty Fourteen is defined in /wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/style.css at line #847:

```
.site-header {
    background-color: #000;
    max-width: 1260px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

Comment: yes i found this from admin panel, but why i can't found this from folder like before ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: e.g. before i open styles.css and edit this, e.g. now i can't found this, i can only if i open css file from admin panel, why this happend ?

Comment: no idea, but whatever it is isn't an issue with the them itself - it's specific to you and your setup.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try some online css generators like [generatecss.com](http://www.generatecss.com/advanced/responsive-color-menu/) and [css3menu.com](http://css3menu.com/) just to save yourself from coding so much and gets to finish the work on time.

Hope it helps you.